# wp-link-pages in header and footer of the post

Tags: posts, single

I would like to work the wp_link_pages functions a bit.

In header of the post starting with second page I would like to have a link to previous page,

```
Continued from page 1
```

where 1 is the number of the previous page, if is first page will show up nothing.

In the footer of the post I would like them to show up like this:

```
<< Previous Page | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Next Page >>
```

and the current page number should not be linked.

Thanks

Comment: This should be fairly simple. What have you tried, _exactly_, and what doesn't work? Post your code please.

Comment: I tried with Wordpress Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links) but could not find the right parameters. I know its easy, but I don't know how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the header

First of all you have to know how retrieve the current page, that is done by

```
get_query_var('page')
```

Knowing it, writing what you want is easy. It can be a little hard if you want to link the previous page correctly. In this case you have to use an *internal* function of wordpress, `_wp_link_page`:

```
$now = get_query_var('page');
if  ( $now > 1 ) {
  $prev = $now-1;
  $anchor =  sprintf( __('Continued from page %d'), $prev );
  $prev_link = _wp_link_page( $prev ) . $anchor . '</a>';
  echo '<p>' . apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $prev_link, $prev ) . '</p>';
}
```

### For the footer

If you see at [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) for `wp_link_pages` you understand that the behavior of this function is usually showing page number **or** showing next and previous link, not both as you want.
For me, solution is create a customized version of the function, putting next code in the `functions.php`:

```
function wp_link_pages_customized() {
  global $page, $numpages, $multipage;
  if ( $multipage ) {
    $output = '';
    $prev =  ( $page < 2 ) ? false : _wp_link_page( $page-1 ) . __('&laquo; Previous page ') . '</a>';
    $next =  ( $page == $numpages ) ? false : _wp_link_page( $page+1 ) . __('Next page &raquo;') . '</a>';
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $numpages; $i++ ) {
      if ( $i != $page ) {
        $output .= _wp_link_page( $i ) . $i . '</a> | ';
      } else {
        $output .= $i . ' | ';
      }
    }
    if ( $prev ) $output = $prev . ' | ' . $output;
    $output = ( $next ) ? $output . $next : rtrim($output, '| ');
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

and then, in the footer template, simply use like so:

```
<p><?php wp_link_pages_customized(); ?></p>
```

Comment: On line 4 for the footer code, you've missed a comma :) . How can I make to have the full "Continued from page 1" a link ? Not just the page number. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the comma and edited the code to make all "Continued from page 1" clickable. I've not tested, but should works

Comment: The header code works just fine, I would like to slightly change the footer code so it will output the separators between page number as no linkable, right now the "after" "|" element is linkable. Thanks again and sorry for asking so many things, I would definitely should start learning PHP. Also the footer code makes the closest text linkable when is on first page.

Comment: @RobertRamsey edited completely the code for the footer. Now it should work as you want.